# SQLITE and iPhone Input Sanitisation

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sanitization

We are making our very first iPhone game, and if the user gets a high score then we need to let them enter their name to store it in the high-scores database inside the app.

What I was wondering is how do we go about sanitising the input on the iPhone. Obviously we don't want them dropping tables when inputting their name!

Can anybody please offer any advice or a push in the right direction?

Thanks,
Dwaine

Comment: Are you using SQLite directly or are you using Core Data with an SQL store?

Comment: I'm using SQLite directly I think...I just created an SQLite database in Terminal, added it to the project, and then I make sqlite3 calls on it like:

    static char *sql = "INSERT INTO scores (hsName, hsScore) VALUES (?, ?)";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, sql, -1, &writeScoresStmt, NULL);

And then binding the values using sqlite3_bind_text and sqlite3_bind_int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you should be using parameterized queries.

For example:

```
sqlite3_reset(insertStatement);

sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, [userInput UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStatement))
{
    //handle error

//etc...
```

You could also use Core Data and rely on it to handle the implementation details.  That'd be my recommendation.

Comment: Hi Don,

This is what I am doing. I'm just worried about people trying to drop my tables or delete the database when entering their name.

Or does this get around that?

Comment: Yes, SQL injection attacks assume you are building the query string in memory.  Parameterized queries using, say, string data will only allow string data and will treat the input as a string.  That is, if they try to get you to execute `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'a';DROP TABLE users;` it will be sent to the database as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = "'a';DROP TABLE users;"`.